# Disk not detected, sata timeout?

Tags: sata

Have a SSD disk that I shall update the FW on but it is not detected in Ubuntu, but in w10 it's detected.

dmesg say:

```
[ 382.097821] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 382.098107] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 387.269789] ata5.00: qc timeout (cmd 0x27)
[ 387.269799] ata5.00: failed to read native max address (err_mask=0x4)
[ 387.269800] ata5.00: HPA support seems broken, skipping HPA handling
[ 392.621743] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 397.305726] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[ 402.657695] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 407.337666] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[ 412.689633] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 442.357439] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[ 442.357448] ata5: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[ 447.409414] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[ 447.409423] ata5: reset failed, giving up
```

Could it be that the ata timeout to soon? Is't possible to extend it?

Comment: Please update the firmware in Windows.

Comment: hdparm --fwdownload is not working in windows.

Comment: Are you sure you're following the manufacturer's instructions? If so, it may have  problem.

Comment: No, the Samsung magician say "drive is not supported" so I can't update whit it in windows.

Comment: Nothing to do then, except hope tha a UEFI update improves device detection.

Comment: BIOS is detecting the disk if you men that by the UEFI.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, using the correct terminology. UEFI replaced BIOS many years ago but userr and some manufacturers, unfortunately, keep using the old, now incorrect, terminology. Yes, you should update it, if available, even if the drive is detect there and works in Windows.

Comment: Desktop or laptop? What make/model/size SSD?

Comment: Both desktop and laptop, the w10 is a desktop. Have run Ubuntu on the w10 HW to test also. Samsung 850 EVO 120GB.

Comment: Is't possible to manually add the disk so hdparm can access it?